# Combine 2 rows in a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a number of rows in a cell array with lots of extra space at the end of the rows as such:

```
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' [] [] [] [] []
'1' '2' '3' [] [] [] [] [] []
'w' 'x' 'y' 'z' [] [] [] [] []
```

I would like to copy the second row onto the end of the first row, as such:

```
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' '1' '2' '3' [] []
'1' '2' '3' [] [] [] [] [] []
'w' 'x' 'y' 'z' [] [] [] [] []
```

Please note that the code given above is an arbitrary example to demonstrate what I wish to do. In reality I will include this functionality as a step in a more complex function.

I have tried searching for the first empty element in the cell array row, but for some reason isempty does not see them as empty. Is there an alternative method that someone could point me towards?

EDIT:
After the steps carried out above, the second row will be deleted, giving:

```
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' '1' '2' '3' [] []
'w' 'x' 'y' 'z' [] [] [] [] []
```

Although the real cell array will have many more rows than 3.

Comment: In your actual case, do you ONLY have to copy the second row at the end of the first row, or do we have to process more rows too? And what happens to the second and third rows and the rest of the rows (if any) ? Do they stay as they are?

Comment: I will only have to add one row to another. After this the second row will be deleted. There will not be a case where I need to add more than one row to another (ie add both rows 2 and 3 to row 1).

Comment: So, if the second row is to be deleted, what would the output cell array look like? The desired output stated in the question still shows the second row. Edit your question on the desired output to clarify that? And what happens to the third row then?

Comment: I have edited the question. I did not originally include this information as I did not think it was relevant to the question.

Comment: By the way does [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27127529/3293881) give any error? If it doesn't, at the end of the solution, you can remove the second row with `C(2,:) =[];`?

Comment: @Divakar, I did not try your code as Luis' seemed to be a better fit for my needs. I'm not saying that I don't think yours will work, and may yet try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this does what you want. I've denoted your cell array as `c`.

```
n1 = find(cellfun('isempty',c(1,:)), 1); %// first empty cell in row 1
n2 = find(cellfun('isempty',c(2,:)), 1); %// first empty cell in row 2
c(1,n1:n1+n2-2) = c(2,1:n2-1); %// copy the relevant part of row 2 onto row 1
```

This automatically extends your cell horizontally if the number of non-empty cells in row 2 exceeds the number of empty cells in row 1.

Example: input:

```
c = {'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' [] [] [] [] []
'1' '2' '3' [] [] [] [] [] []
'w' 'x' 'y' 'z' [] [] [] [] []}
```

Output:

```
c = 
    'a'    'b'    'c'    'd'    '1'    '2'    '3'    []    []
    '1'    '2'    '3'     []     []     []     []    []    []
    'w'    'x'    'y'    'z'     []     []     []    []    []
```

Comment: Thanks for that. This looks like it should work, however, when running the code I get an error message for 'too many inputs'. Do you know where this error may be coming from?

Comment: I don't get any error for `c` as in Divakar's answer for example. How do you define your `c`?

Comment: @Doragan Make sure to copy and paste as it is and don't remove any round brackets.

Comment: @LuisMendo I define it c=cell(length(CAMINO),500)

Comment: @Divakar I did copy and paste, although I made a couple of changes to get it to work in my original code. I am currently trying again, and seem to be getting different results. I will report back presently.

Comment: @Doragan I've added an example in my question

Comment: @LuisMendo it appears I had made a mistake somewhere on my side. Good code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one general approach that uses the efficient **[`logical indexing`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html#btjk576-1)** to select the non-empty cells, single call to `cellfun('isempty'` and does automatic extension as talked about in [Luis's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27127000/3293881) -

```
C = {
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' [] [] [] [] []
'1' '2' '3' [] [] [] [] [] []
'w' 'x' 'y' 'z' [] [] [] [] []} %// Input cell array

N = 2; %//Number of rows to process, starting from 2 until the number of rows in C
Ct = C'; %//'# Transpose input cell array, as collecting elements that way is easier
vals = Ct(~cellfun('isempty',Ct(:,1:N))); %//'# elements from selected row(s)
C(1,1:numel(vals)) = vals; %// Place the values into the first row
```

With `N = 2` which is the case stated in the problem, output would be -

```
C = 
    'a'    'b'    'c'    'd'    '1'    '2'    '3'    []    []
    '1'    '2'    '3'     []     []     []     []    []    []
    'w'    'x'    'y'    'z'     []     []     []    []    []
```

With `N = 3`, you would copy the second and third rows at the end of the first row. Thus, the output would be -

```
C = 
    'a'    'b'    'c'    'd'    '1'    '2'    '3'    'w'    'x'    'y'    'z'
    '1'    '2'    '3'     []     []     []     []     []     []     []     []
    'w'    'x'    'y'    'z'     []     []     []     []     []     []     []
```

and so on.